# Is there a distribution that implements all of systemd?

Tags: systemd, distributions

Systemd has a lot of parts, including homedir management with `homectl`, locale management with `localectl`, bootloader with `bootctl`, a network resolver with `resolvectl`, and an oom manager with `oomctl`. Is there any distro that follows systemd entirely? Where I can play with all the features of systemd?

Comment: At least Fedora 34 has all the pieces you mention (and the more well-known pieces, obviously). Knowing the Debian folks, I'd be surpeised if they aren't also all available there.

Answer (score 5):

`systemd` is developed primarily by RedHat employees, Fedora is their main testbed distribution for RHEL, so you can imagine that Fedora enables most of `systemd` features.

If you want to be on the bleeding edge you could use Fedora Rawhide which normally contains the latest version and all the newest features of `systemd`.

Answer (score 4):

On Fedora 34 the `systemd` package contains the following executables:

```
busctl, coredumpctl, homectl, hostnamectl, journalctl, localectl,
loginctl, oomctl, portablectl, resolvectl, systemctl, systemd-analyze,
systemd-ask-password, systemd-cat, systemd-cgls, systemd-cgtop,
systemd-cryptenroll, systemd-delta, systemd-detect-virt,
systemd-dissect, systemd-escape, systemd-firstboot, systemd-id128,
systemd-inhibit, systemd-machine-id-setup, systemd-mount,
systemd-notify, systemd-path, systemd-resolve, systemd-run,
systemd-socket-activate, systemd-stdio-bridge, systemd-sysext,
systemd-sysusers, systemd-tmpfiles, systemd-tty-ask-password-agent,
systemd-umount, timedatectl, userdbct
```

I dunno if some is missing.

Comment: Looking at [the `spec` file](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/systemd/blob/rawhide/f/systemd.spec) suggests that everything is enabled.